# List index out of range error list reduced while iteration

Tags: python, list

I think I'm getting an error because the range of the list is reduced during iteration of the loop. I have 95 nested lists within a large list `mega4`, and I'm trying to delete some strings with if and else. The list `ufields` consist of 18 strings.

```
>>> for i in range(len(mega4)):
...     for j in range(len(mega4[i])):
...         for f in ufields:
...             if (f in mega4[i][j]) is False:
...                 mega4[i].remove(mega4[i][j])
...             else:
...                 pass
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range
```

The fourth line is basically asking if each element within `mega4[i]` has each strings within `ufields`, how can I remove the `mega4[i][j]` in this case?

Edit:

I followed comments below and tried building a new list but this one does not seem to work

```
>>> mega5 = []
>>> for i in range(len(mega4)):
...     for f in ufields:
...         mega5.append([x for x in mega4[i] if f in x is True])
```

`len(mega5)` is larger than `len(mega4)` whereas it should be the same.

Comment: Removing items from a list (or other collection) that you're iterating over is generally not a good idea. You _can_ do it safely if you iterate backwards, so that the removal doesn't change the indices of items you haven't seen yet. But it's generally more efficient just to build a new list containing the desired items because each time you remove an item from a list all the subsequent items need to be moved down.

Answer (score 1):

1. Depending on how `ufields` is defined, you could eliminate the innermost loop by using `if mega4[i][j] in ufields`.
2. Instead of modifying `mega4` within this loop, you could build up a list of what elements you *want* to eliminate, and then do the actual elimination afterwards (looping over your list of candidates instead of `mega4` itself).

Answer (score 1):

Simpler way:

```
result = [[sub for sub in item if sub] for item in mega4]
```

Your way wasn't working because you were editing list while iterating over it.

Comment: How is that different from  mega5 = [x for x in mega4[i] if (f in x) is True]?

Comment: `is True` and `if sub` are completely different. `if sub` is short for `if not False`.